# Create graph from data frame - rows as vertices and common column values as edges?

Tags: r, networking, graph, igraph

I’m having a bit of trouble using [graph_from_data_frame](https://igraph.org/r/doc/graph_from_data_frame.html) properly - ERROR: ... the data frame should contain at least two columns when it already does.

I have a data frame, lets use a cohort of students as an example.

Each row is a student name, and there are multiple columns of metadata, most of which irrelevant. I would like to use one specific column “Class”, denoting which class they’re in (lets they're in 15 classes of 30 each). I would like to make a graph such that every student is a vertex, and students with the same value in the “Class” column get an undirected edge.

How would this command look like?

Just an update to add some context: the number of nodes/edges I wished to plot were ***incredibly*** large (it's not literally a class of students), so much so that the 1-to-1 representations used in the examples would be unfeasible. Hence, I was looking for a more efficient way to encode edges.

Comment: Make your dataframe as similar as possible to the example dataframe in the documentation you linked. Especially re-ordering the columns.

Comment: My dataframe is already ~13000 rows, the example looks like a new row will have to be made for every pair in the same "Class". With 15 classes (Assume equally distributed), my new dataframe would be ~ (866! * 15) rows... Can R handle such large dataframes?

Comment: Does the example code from the documentation work? Rather than one huge dataframe, you might need two: students and classes.

Comment: I'm having a little trouble converting my data to the documentation's format. Their 2nd dataframe (relations) also represent 1:1 edges, with other metadata. Without the metadata, for my application this would still be  ~(866! * 15) rows. E.g. it would look like from=c(Bob, Bob, Bob ... Bob30, ... Cecil... n), to=c(Alice, Cecil, David ... all-in-same-class-as-bob, repeat for the other 29, this time with Bob instead of Cecil, ... n)? Are there more efficient ways to obtain edges from a common metadata?

Comment: My guess is you are trying to make a students-to-students chart, but are working with students-to-class data. What have you tried? Please considered pen-and-paper drawing a simplified version of your desired chart. And, rather than deal with your large dataframe, consider making a toy version with a handful of records to test your code. Finally, perhaps look at other graph libraries such as https://christophergandrud.github.io/networkD3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(igraph)

df = tibble(
  class = c("1","1","1","2","2","2","3","3","3"), 
  name = c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i")
)

names = df %>% select(name)
relations = df %>% 
  mutate(name2 = df$name)

for (i in unique(select(df,class))$class){
  from = relations %>%
    filter(class == i) %>%
    select(name)

  to = relations %>%
    filter(class == i) %>%
    select(name2)

  # Form relationships between all students in each class
  if (i == 1){edge_list = tidyr::crossing(from, to)} 
  else {edge_list = bind_rows(edge_list, tidyr::crossing(from, to))}
}

# Prevent self-loop edges and duplicate relationships
edge_list = edge_list %>% filter(name != name2) 
edge_list = edge_list[!duplicated(t(apply(edge_list, 1, sort))), ]

plot(graph_from_data_frame(edge_list, directed = FALSE, vertices = names))
```

[image: Resulting Plot]